# How to resolve “The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found”

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I´m testing my in-app billing and followed the following steps:

Uploaded APK to the Market, created In-App items and published them (did not publish the app itself), exported a signed APK and installed that on a different device then my own (so there is a different primary account), but when I click on the button to purchase an item, it shows the itemname in a different view, but after a loading widget it gives the error:

How to resolve “The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found

I couldn´t find the solution on stackoverflow, can anyone give me more ideas?

Thanks

Comment: this link is also helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/A2RM4P34zo0

Comment: I had an app published for open testing. Had same issue on motorola while other phones worked fine. Restart the phone solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the app is not published, then the account you are using must be declared as a test account, check it here:

[Setting Test accounts.](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Comment: Recently, it becomes not to work well. I contact Google. They replied that the alpha or beta release is necessary to test In-App Billing.

Comment: How long it take after you upload to beta or alpha... mine is still not working but was 2 weeks ago.  And yes i'm using a test account

Comment: Still not working even with the app published in Beta and using a test account.

Comment: This is no longer valid in 2024! The link does not point to the right section either.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have done all these steps:

- The `versionCode` of the app you're running has to be the same as the apk you have loaded in the Google Play Console.
- The account you are using for testing is not the same account you are using to public the app in the play store;
- The account you are using for testing has been declared as a test account. If not [set your account as a tester](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777);
- Your app has **to be published** in the Play Store. If you are testing your app you probably want to publish it in the Internal testing section. If your app is "In review", the app has not been published yet, hence in-app purchases won't work.;
- If your app has just been published it might take a few hours to make In-app purchases work;
- If you have just created an In-app product, you might have to wait a few hours before it actually works.

You can find the **complete tutorial** on how to implement In-App Purchases [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/implementing-in-app-purchases-in-android-2bd52a3ab700)

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that you didn't add the item on Google play developer console under **in-app product**

**Steps to add item**

1. Login with Developer account in [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/.).
2. Select Your App.
3. From left side Select **In-app Products**
4. Click on "**+ Add new product**" button
5. Add new Product window in open. Now enter **product id** and select **Item Type**
6. Click on "**Continue**"
7. Now new window is open. Now enter Title,Description,Price
8. Click on **Save** or **Activate** button

**Note :**
If you click on **Save** button then the item is only saved in your in-app products and it's still not active to use. you have to manually activate the item and wait for 2 or 3 hours to be active.

**Most important :**
If you want to activate your item immediately then you have to click on **Activate** button at **step 8**. it will activate your item immediately and save it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add your testers' accounts across all apps by following how to [User-test a Google Play Billing app](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-purchases) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

To test your Google Play Billing Library integration using test tracks, do the following:

Publish your app to a test track. Note that after you publish an app to a testing track, it can take a few hours for the app to be available for testers.
Ensure each tester opts-in to your app's test. On your test's opt-in URL, your testers see an explanation of what it means to be a tester along with a link to opt-in.
[Test your Google Play Billing Library integration](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)

Answer (score 0):

For me, Internal testing didn't work. After I created Closed testing (Alpha) and added testers, it worked!