# "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found" error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a free game on Play Store with the ability to unlock full game by making an in-app purchase.
When users try to purchase that item, they get this error: "**The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found**".
The item is published and active. Some months ago there were no problems. What do you think it is the cause?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743429/how-to-resolve-the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found)  and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918190/the-item-you-were-attempting-to-purchase-could-not-be-found-android-in-app-bil)

Comment: Unluckily my question is a little different, because my app is published. In the questions you linked, the problem was that the app was not published, so testing IAPs didn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: So your app is published on the Play Store? Have you published a new release? What have you changed from the previous release?

Comment: Yes, my app is published on the Play Store as stable (not Beta nor Alpha). The problem started many months ago: even before publishing a new version, in-app purchase stopped working also in testing. I didn't change anything in the IAP code. After months of tries, I decided to publish the new version anyway, thinking that maybe the problem was only with testing. But the problem persists also when real users try to make IAP with the released version.

Comment: Do you use the last version (V3) of the [Google In App Billing API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)?

Comment: Yes, V3 of Google In App Billing.